# How can I put on my website a code like the one shown here in Stackoverflow

Tags: php

Recently I started a project to be able to share my codes, but I see the detail that I can not insert the code without the server executing it. I would like to know in what way I can put the code as it does here in stackoverflow.

Example:

```
<? echo'I need to put this type of code.'; ?>
```

Or where I can use the text editor they use here.  I want to view my code similar to [imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/8002/jHual3.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/8002/jHual3.png).  The code syntax is all the code in my web page.

Comment: use English on SO. use **[Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)**

Comment: English language pls .

Comment: please use english

Comment: i'm start with a new proyect and i need to post my source code in my web page, can you help me because i'm use my source code my server run my code and my public cant see the code, sorry i'm forget post in english.

Comment: Either `<?php echo` or `<?=` not `<? echo` http://php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver no, i want view my code similar to http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/8002/jHual3.png  the code syntaxis all the code! in my web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to view the code of a PHP page, then you can read the file and apply syntax highlighting. There's a function for that:

```
echo highlight_file('/path/to/file.php');
```

To highlight the running file:

```
echo highlight_file(__FILE__);
```

If your webserver supports it you can just rename the file `.phps` and it will display highlighted when executed.  Apache would need this in `httpd.conf`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```